# How to plot multiple lines per facet using facet_grid (in ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

**My problem**

Ideally, I want to use ggplot2 to create a plot that has 6 facets (3 by 2, for each unique combination of angle and group - see data below) and four lines per facet (2 x 2 for side by view, see data below), where the x- and y-values for each line are rotation and predvalue. However, including both in a single figure makes the data disappear.

*my apologies, I cannot post images due to lack of reputation, so I've edited them out for now and will try to insert them later - of course it's also fine if someone else edits them in.*

My data look like this (see dput of full data at the end of this post):

```
> head(sub.y)
     side view rotation angle age  predval
1706    l back      120     0 old 1.322787
1694    l back      120   300 old 1.847914
1739    l back      120    60 old 1.332836
1744    l back      240     0 old 1.157399
1725    l back      240   300 old 1.540411
1713    l back      240    60 old 1.165085
```

I can produce (nonsensical, because they contain repeats of rotation) lines in a single facet:

```
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.y, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = view:side, colour = side, linetype = view))
```

[lines in single facet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7ggm.png)

I can also create facets, but if I add them to the plot, all lines disappear:

```
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.y, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = view:side, colour = side, linetype = view))
tmp.fig + facet_grid(rows = angle ~ age)
```

[facets but no lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ja6.png)

The same happens if I simplify the plot by reducing each interaction to a single factor (image not included):

```
sub.y2 = droplevels(subset(sub.y,age == "young" & side == "r")) 
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.y2, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = view))
tmp.fig + facet_grid(rows = vars(angle))
```

The closest I have come to the desired outcome is to subset by angle and age, and produce a single facet:

```
sub.single = subset(sub.y, angle =="60" & age == "young")
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.single, aes(x = rotation, y = predval, group = comb, colour = s))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = comb, colour = side, linetype = view))
```

[single facet, correct lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM4PT.png)

**Other things I have tried**

- The same with rotation as either a numerical variable or an unordered factor.
- Using the new notation for facet_grid, i.e.:

```
facet_grid(row = vars(angle), cols = vars(age))
```

- Combining side and view into a single variable and use that for grouping, e.g.:

```
sub.y$comb = factor(paste0(sub.y$side, sub.y$view))
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.y, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = view))
tmp.fig + facet_grid(rows = angle ~ age)
```

- Subsetting to eliminate repeats in rotation within each unique combination of angle and age:

```
sub.lpalm = subset(sub.y,comb == "lpalm")
```

- Also in combination with specifying fixed values for colour and linetype:

```
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.lpalm, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(x = rotation, y = predval), colour = "red", linetype = 2)
tmp.fig + facet_grid(rows = angle ~ age)
```

**My questions**

- Is it possible to do this directly in ggplot2?
- If yes: how?
- If no: what would be the best workaround? Is there one within ggplot2? Or do I need to switch to par(mfrow)/layout/split.screen?

This is the complete dataset:

```
sub.y = structure(list(side = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("l", "r"), class = "factor"), 
    view = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("back", 
    "palm"), class = "factor"), rotation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("60", "120", "240", "300"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), angle = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
    "300", "60"), class = "factor"), age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("old", "young"), class = "factor"), 
    predval = c(1.32278735306685, 1.84791387068062, 1.33283630791921, 
    1.15739906981041, 1.54041056424184, 1.16508497061474, 1.07521745696964, 
    1.39817944551224, 1.08184750079453, 1.12479365463523, 1.48318811113428, 
    1.1320512540569, 1.39380248667788, 1.26377942966172, 1.30745255320685, 
    1.69059385166861, 1.50302783162468, 1.56520862954539, 1.54867304027266, 
    1.38979681736988, 1.44279652008074, 1.43351747463353, 1.29634372314341, 
    1.34233748386223, 1.12608718760191, 1.48543811583713, 1.13336154334054, 
    1.21240995016786, 1.63941177663727, 1.22084649460943, 1.07662100847547, 
    1.40055372523695, 1.08326842636178, 0.994888143137882, 1.26532710222997, 
    1.00056192025627, 1.77947866922719, 1.57287633657913, 1.64110190502596, 
    1.30305741118218, 1.18871937048205, 1.2272796256123, 1.32008919689553, 
    1.20287711129925, 1.24237660794742, 1.6083792173394, 1.43769159033688, 
    1.4944817898592, 1.21942340929136, 1.65226153894706, 1.22795818578818, 
    1.0774857498948, 1.40201746905525, 1.08414388349372, 1.00591000333728, 
    1.28320933888409, 1.01171055708072, 1.04917234385345, 1.35445633709304, 
    1.05548413456299, 1.27952165685907, 1.16910164994662, 1.20637971253239, 
    1.52534725655376, 1.37098239147552, 1.42253022462099, 1.40885870946257, 
    1.27614512965268, 1.32069215403839, 1.31291299288743, 1.19691581894265, 
    1.23601841416658, 1.05029770489711, 1.35633247083872, 1.05662308396455, 
    1.12500641475433, 1.48355807827798, 1.13226676891647, 1.00713834011054, 
    1.28520892651887, 1.01295310979221, 0.935262602075179, 1.17042599521691, 
    0.94027496475633, 1.59733529275344, 1.4288609015962, 1.48494199557954, 
    1.20263686648971, 1.10457968208415, 1.13779812715232, 1.21713008591452, 
    1.11679383676805, 1.15076228140728, 1.4580995773513, 1.31641344398338, 
    1.36386842665239)), row.names = c(1706L, 1694L, 1739L, 1744L, 
1725L, 1713L, 1733L, 1720L, 1729L, 1728L, 1730L, 1708L, 1761L, 
1763L, 1742L, 1804L, 1787L, 1712L, 1778L, 1722L, 1709L, 1714L, 
1747L, 1699L, 1751L, 1737L, 1779L, 1726L, 1935L, 1781L, 1719L, 
1905L, 1723L, 1735L, 1760L, 1762L, 1780L, 1836L, 1773L, 1767L, 
1768L, 1785L, 1753L, 1701L, 1695L, 1774L, 1783L, 1765L, 5621L, 
5618L, 5592L, 5598L, 5596L, 5557L, 5612L, 5565L, 5532L, 5540L, 
5562L, 5578L, 5539L, 5567L, 5544L, 5560L, 5704L, 5611L, 5607L, 
5599L, 5603L, 5555L, 5561L, 5576L, 5552L, 5604L, 5615L, 5564L, 
5693L, 5593L, 5569L, 5556L, 5614L, 5580L, 5610L, 5591L, 5714L, 
5589L, 5602L, 5597L, 5590L, 5729L, 5546L, 5617L, 5716L, 5726L, 
5720L, 5642L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your middle example seems to work fine for me: `ggplot(sub.y, aes(x = rotation, y = predval)) + geom_line(aes(group = view:side, colour = side, linetype = view)) + facet_grid(rows = angle ~ age)`

Comment: You are right, and thanks to your help I've identified the problem with my examples: I used ```tmp.fig + ... ``` instead of ```tmp.fig = tmp.fig + ...```. The second change therefore overwrote the first, instead of being added to it. If you post your comment in the form of an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small typo in the middle code, where you mean to use `tmp.fig = tmp.fig +...` but are missing the `tmp.fig =`. This means the `+ geom_line()` in the 2nd line isn't included in the third line, hence no lines in the plot.

```
sub.y2 = droplevels(subset(sub.y,age == "young" & side == "r")) 
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.y2, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = view))  
tmp.fig + facet_grid(rows = vars(angle))
```

Option 1: Add `tmp.fig = ...` to revise the plot object incrementally

```
sub.y2 = droplevels(subset(sub.y,age == "young" & side == "r")) 
tmp.fig = ggplot(sub.y2, aes(x = rotation, y = predval))
tmp.fig = tmp.fig + geom_line(aes(group = view))  
tmp.fig = tmp.fig + facet_grid(rows = vars(angle))
```

Option 2: Build plot in one connected stream

```
ggplot(sub.y, aes(x = rotation, y = predval)) + 
geom_line(aes(group = view:side, colour = side, linetype = view)) + 
facet_grid(rows = angle ~ age)
```